# List View failing to draw strings

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi

I am trying to use a list view to draw a vector of `std::strings` as a list. However, when I run the code, nothing happens. No error is thrown: it just simple doesn't draw, and I'm stumped. Here is a minimal reproducible example (the bulk of the code that I am questioning is in the `WndProc` under `case WM_NOTIFY` and `InsertListViewItems`):

```
    //libraries
    #pragma comment ("lib", "Comctl32.lib")
    
    #include "targetver.h"
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
    // Windows Header Files
    #include <windows.h>
    // C RunTime Header Files
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <memory.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <dwrite.h>
    #include <d2d1.h>
    #include <commctrl.h> 
    #include <strsafe.h>
    
    #define IDS_APP_TITLE           103
    #define IDR_MAINFRAME           128
    #define IDD_PRACTICE_DIALOG 102
    #define IDD_ABOUTBOX            103
    #define IDM_EXIT                105
    #define IDI_PRACTICE            107
    #define IDI_SMALL               108
    #define IDC_PRACTICE            109
    #define IDC_MYICON              2
    #ifndef IDC_STATIC
    #define IDC_STATIC              -1
    #endif
    #define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
    
    #define PROJECT_LIST_VIEW     110
    // Global Variables:
    HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
    WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
    WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
    
    std::vector<std::string> stringsVector = { "String1", "String2", "string3" };
    
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    
    HWND listViewHandle;
    
    ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
    {
        WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
        wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
        wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PRACTICE));
        wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_PRACTICE);
        wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
        wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
        return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
    }
    BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
    {
        hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable
        HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
        if (!hWnd)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);
        return TRUE;
    }
    ///////////////////
    //Function to insert the items into the list view
    //////////////////
    BOOL InsertListViewItems(HWND hWndListView, int cItems)
    {
        LVITEM lvI;
        // Initialize LVITEM members that are common to all items.
        lvI.pszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK; //This should send an LVN_GETDISPINFO message
        lvI.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_STATE;
        lvI.stateMask = 0;
        lvI.iSubItem = 0;
        lvI.state = 0;
    
        // Initialize LVITEM members that are different for each item.
        for (int index = 0; index < cItems; index++)
        {
            lvI.iItem = index;
            lvI.iImage = index;
    
            // Insert items into the list.
            if (ListView_InsertItem(hWndListView, &lvI) == -1)
                return FALSE;
        }
    
        return TRUE;
    }
    int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
        _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
        _In_ int       nCmdShow)
    {
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
        // Initialize global strings
        LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
        LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_PRACTICE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
        MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
        // Perform application initialization:
        if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PRACTICE));
        MSG msg;
        // Main message loop:
        while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
        {
            if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        return (int)msg.wParam;
    }
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
            //Create the List View Control
            listViewHandle = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS, 100, 100, 500, 500, hWnd, (HMENU)PROJECT_LIST_VIEW, hInst, NULL);
            InsertListViewItems(listViewHandle, stringsVector.size());
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            NMLVDISPINFO* plvdi;
            OutputDebugStringA("WM_NOTIFY");
            switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
            {
            case LVN_GETDISPINFO:
            {
                ////////////////////
                //This is the callback that should set the pszText attribute of the items
                ////////////////////
                OutputDebugStringA("LVN_GETDISPINFO\n");
    
                plvdi = (NMLVDISPINFO*)lParam;
    
                const char* inString = stringsVector[plvdi->item.iItem].c_str();
                size_t size = strlen(inString) + 1;
                wchar_t* outString = new wchar_t[size];
    
                size_t outSize;
                mbstowcs_s(&outSize, outString, size, inString, size - 1);
                LPWSTR ptr = outString;
    
                StringCchCopy(plvdi->item.pszText, plvdi->item.cchTextMax, outString);
                OutputDebugString(outString);
                OutputDebugStringA("\n");
                delete[] outString;
                break;
            }
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You have lots of debug messages in your code.  Are they output?  You say "it does nothing".  That could mean anything.  You should at least identify for the reader which parts of the code are being entered.  For example, is _any_ window shown at all?  Is the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` being processed?  Does your program crash?  Describe the actual behavior in detail.

Comment: Since your listview is in report (details) mode, you need to add at least one column using `LVM_INSERTCOLUMN` before any contents will be visible.

Comment: Hi @paddy, when I said it that is does nothing, I meant that it doesn't draw the strings, not that it literally doesn't run. In fact, it seems to run normally just without having drawn the text. Sorry for not having been more clear.

Comment: @JuanitaLopez Nowhere in this code is `InsertListViewItems()` ever being called to actually add any items to the list view. In your `WM_CREATE` handler, after you create the list view, you need to add a column to the list view like JonathanPotter said, and then you need to call `InsertListViewItems(listViewHandle, stringsVector.size())`

Comment: Sorry @Remy Lebeau, I forgot to add that when I transcribe the code. When I was running it and having my problem (nothing being drawn), I did call the function.

Comment: @JuanitaLopez "*I forgot to add that when I transcribe the code*" - you should always **copy/paste your real code** when possible. But what JonathanPotter said still stands - in `LVS_REPORT` style, you must add columns to the ListView, otherwise the strings can't be displayed. You need a separate column for `LVITEM::iItem` and each `LVITEM::iSubItem`. See [List-View Columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#list-view-columns) and [How to Add List -View Columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/add-list-view-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jonathan Potter and Remy said, you need to add at least one column to ensure that the list is displayed correctly:

```
LVCOLUMN lvc;
lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
// Initialize LVITEM members that are common to all items.

// Initialize LVITEM members that are different for each item.
lvc.iSubItem = 0;
lvc.pszText = (LPWSTR)L"test";
lvc.cx = 200;
// Insert items into the list.
if (ListView_InsertColumn(hWndListView, 0, &lvc) == -1)
    return FALSE;
```

And it works for me:

[image]

More reference: [How to Add List-View Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/add-list-view-columns)